# UserDetailsService is never called(Spring boot security)

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I have this SpringSecurity config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl detailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(detailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").access("hasRole('USER')");
        http.userDetailsService(detailsService);
    }
}
```

when I open `index.html` page I get 403 error. It is because user is `anonymous`. But I want check user and set role and detail before opened this page. For this i write this service

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        AuthLkUser authLkUserByIp = authService.getAuthLkUserByIp(ipAddress);

        if (authLkUserByIp == null) return null;

        boolean b = authService.checkAuthLkUser(authLkUserByIp);
        if (b) return null;
        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet();
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(authLkUserByIp.getMsisdn(),
                        authLkUserByIp.getSubsId(), roles);
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

But this service is never called.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot if you have a custom Spring Security Configuration then it will not use Auto Configuration for Spring Security.

In your Spring security configuration you haven't given anyway to authenticate a user. There are form based, basic header based, etc authentication available in Spring Security. You should use one of that to authenticate user so that during authentication your `UserDetailsServiceImpl` will be used to load the user.

Follow this [post](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RC1/reference/html/jc.html) for form based login